# How to 'getConstructor' where constructor signature contains java array

Tags: java, reflection

Is it possible to use getConstructor to obtain the constructor of the class X below?

```
public class A {
}

public class Y {

}

public class X extends Y {
    public X(A a, Y[] yy) {

    }
    public void someMethod() throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException {
        Class<? extends Y> clazz = X.class;
        Constructor<? extends Y> c =
            clazz.getConstructor(new Class[]{
                        A.class,
                        /* what do I put in here for the array of Ys? */
                    });
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can construct class literals involving array notation just like you would with "undecorated" classes, namely `ClassName[].class`. This literal yields "the class which describes arrays of instances of `ClassName`". In your case:

```
clazz.getConstructor(new Class[] {
    A.class,
    Y[].class
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

Or shorter.

```
    Constructor<X> c = X.class.getConstructor(A.class, Y[].class);
```